# Is there a difference between the PMP and the CAPM in terms of what to study?

Tags: education, certification, pmi-framework, capm

I have seen that many websites claim that they have brain dumps for CAPM like they said they have for CISCO, Java and Microsoft. I am **strictly** saying that I am not going to use those dumps and nor I recommend anyone to use that because they do nothing but decrease your knowledge. But I am curious to know this:

Will the study material for the CAPM certification be different than the study material for the PMP? What is the difference?

Does CAPM have a definite set of questions for the exam like CISCO, Java and Microsoft?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CAPM is based on the same information and knowledge required for the PMP, just not as in-depth. So any training or sample questions you find for the PMP will apply to the CAPM. For study, the primary text is the PMBoK Guide, and while PMI says it's not the only text, I didn't see anything in the exam that wasn't covered in the Guide. Rita Mulchahy's book is supposed to be pretty good if you find the Guide too dry.

And no, no brain dump is required. If you know how to manage projects, then read the Guide, try some sample exams, and take the exam.

Answer (score 0):

the course content is same for CAPM and PMP- the only difference being CAPM is an entry level certification so the syllabus is not in-depth as compared to PMP. The exam pattern is also different for CAPM and the difficulty level is a much less as compared to PMP. You can read these [resources](http://www.simplilearn.com/resources) to know more about the two certifications. I hope this helps! Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Overview of CAPM & PMP**

CAPM is an entry level certification for people who are working in projects. It is a knowledge based test based on the PMBOK Guide. If you study hard, you can easily pass the exam. You need to study PMBOK Guide and learn about the processes & ITTOs.

PMP is an advanced level certification for people who are managing complete project or part of a project i.e. they have experience of leading & directing projects. PMP is mostly based on the PMBOK Guide but not entirely on it. It is based on Project Manager's role as defined by the PMI. PMP tests the aspirants on the application of PMBOK Guide's concepts (Processes & ITTOs) and hence it is much more difficult than CAPM.

**CAPM Requirement**

There are 2 ways to fulfill the requirement to appear in the CAPM Exam -
Option 1 - You need to have high school diploma or global equivalent with 1500 hours of professional experience on a project team

Option 2 - You need to have high school diploma or global equivalent with 23 contact hours of formal education.

**Contact Hours**

You can gain contact hours by doing an online course. I would recommend that you should look at some [top courses on udemy](http://www.pmbypm.com/top-udemy-courses-project-management/). Udemy courses are reasonably priced and you get lifetime access to the course.